# Is there a query to retrieve all source table names and target table names of a particular mapping in informatica?

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is there any query that results from source table names and column table names using a mapping or mapping Id in informatica. This has been very hard and challenging

Like when we search up `SELECT * FROM opb_mapping WHERE mapping_name LIKE '%CY0..%'`

It is resulting in some details but I cannot find source table names and target table names. Help if you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below view to get the data.
(Assuming you have full access to metadata tables.

```
select source_name, source_field_name,
target_name, target_column_name,
mapping_name, subject_name folder
from REP_FLD_MAPPING
where mapping_name like '%xx%';
```

Only issue i can see is, if you have overwrite sql, then you need to check sql for true source.